# Java map with lists of objects to list

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
public class CarShop {
    private final HashMap<Brand, List<CarPrototype>> catalog;

    public List<CarPrototype> allPrototypes() {
        List<CarPrototype> prototypes = catalog.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
        return prototypes ;
    }
```

What I want to do in this method is I want to get a list of all different car prototypes given in car shop catalog. I should not use for loop, so stream comes into play. My solution is adds only lists of prototypes, and I struggle finding how to change it so it add specific prototypes themselves.

Comment: That is a bizzarde to have requiremet to NOT use most common solutions to known problems since the beginning of programming.

Comment: Well, is there any solution then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Stream<List<Foo>>` and want to convert it to `List<Foo>` you can use `flatMap`:

```java
Stream<List<Foo>> stream = ...;
Stream<Foo> flatStream = stream.flatMap(List::stream);
List<Foo> list = flatStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For your specific example:

```java
public List<CarPrototype> allPrototypes() {
    List<CarPrototype> prototypes = catalog.values().stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return prototypes;
}
```